# Can't find the dll file in downloaded project for visual studio?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, dll

This is my first time using a dll file in visual studio, the installation guide says, to go to add references and locate the specifed file which is a .dll file however when I search the entire folder/pc for such a file I don't get any results?[This is the guide I am following](http://smiley22.github.io/S22.Imap/Documentation/)

Comment: Have you downloaded the software to your PC?

Comment: Do you mean the source file? If so then yes I have downloaded the project from the provided link.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/quickstart/install-and-use-a-package-in-visual-studio

Comment: If you've downloaded the source you'll need to compile it to create the dll.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add the assembly as a nuget packet!
right click on your project tree in Visual Studio and select Nuget Package Manager and add S22.Imap!

https://www.nuget.org/packages/S22.Imap/

Comment: Thanks I will try that, is there a reason why I couldn't do it following the guide?

Comment: @kosak you link to the guide points to the github repo https://github.com/smiley22/S22.Imap . They recommend to download the lib as Nuget and then are saying to add the .dll as reference, which is not necessary, when you use Nuget. strange or wrong docs in their site.